# Dibujar bordes PDFDocument Android

Tags: java, android, pdf

Estoy tratando de dibujar **bordes** en mi aplicación `Android` a la hora de crear un `PDF`, el problema que tengo es que estos no se visualizs. Básicamente, no se ven. He estado buscando pero no encontré algo que se adecue a mi necesidad. Este es el método que uso para **dibujar** los **bordes**:

```
public void CrearPDF(String fechaHoy, Context context){
    try{
        PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument();
        PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(600, 850, 1).create();
        PdfDocument.Page page = pdfDocument.startPage(pageInfo);

        Paint fillPaint = new Paint();
        Paint strokePaint = new Paint();

        RectF r = new RectF(60, 60, 60, 60);
        //fill
        fillPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        fillPaint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);

        // stroke
        strokePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        strokePaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        strokePaint.setStrokeWidth(10);
        
        //primer rectángulo
        page.getCanvas().drawRect(r, fillPaint);    // fill
        page.getCanvas().drawRect(r, strokePaint);  // stroke

        page.getCanvas().translate(0, 600);

        // Segundo rectángulo
        int cornerRadius = 50;
        page.getCanvas().drawRoundRect(r, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, fillPaint);    // fill
        page.getCanvas().drawRoundRect(r, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, strokePaint); //stroke

        page.getCanvas().drawColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.blanco));
        pdfDocument.finishPage(page);

        String nombreDirectorio = "/Mi Taller/Reportes Diarios";
        String rutaDirectorio = "/sdcard"
                + "/"
                + nombreDirectorio;
        File ruta = new File(rutaDirectorio);
        if (!ruta.exists() || !ruta.isDirectory()) {
            CrearDirectorio(nombreDirectorio);
        }
        String guion = "";
        if (fechaHoy.contains("/")) {
            guion = fechaHoy.replaceAll("/", "-");
        }
        Log.d("guion", "CrearPDF: " + guion);
        File file = new File(ruta, "Reporte "+ guion + ".pdf");
        pdfDocument.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(file));
        pdfDocument.close();
     }catch (Exception e){
       Log.d("CrearPDF", "CrearPDF: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Los bordes en mi **pdf** creado, no se ven, ¿Alguien sabe si estoy errándole a alguna parte?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error está en esta línea

```
RectF r = new RectF(60, 60, 60, 60);
```

Los parámetros del constructor representan los límites del rectángulo. Es decir, las cordenadas de sus vértices en el canvas. Si le das el mismo valor a todos signfica que el rectangulo comienza y termina en el mismo punto. No puedes verlo porque su tamaño es 0.

No sé que intentabas dibujar pero si quieres un rectángulo de 60x60, debes hacer que la distancia entre sus lados sea 60. Ejemplos `RectF(0, 0, 60, 60)`, `RectF(60, 60, 120, 120)`, etc.

El otro error es la ubicación de esta línea

```
page.getCanvas().drawColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.blanco));
```

El método `drawColor()` pinta **todo** el canvas del color que le indiques. Incluso si los rectangulos tuvieran un tamaño visible, no podrías verlos porque al usar `drawColor()` este cubre cualquier cosa que hayas dibujado antes.

Lo que deberías hacer es primero pintar el canvas y luego dibujar los rectángulos

```
// fondo 
page.getCanvas().drawColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.blanco));
// primer rectángulo
page.getCanvas().drawRect(r, fillPaint);
page.getCanvas().drawRect(r, strokePaint);
// Segundo rectángulo
page.getCanvas().drawRoundRect(r, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, fillPaint);
page.getCanvas().drawRoundRect(r, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, strokePaint);
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, efectivamente era eso.